# Where to find the Distribution Group maintenance form in Dynamics AX 2012?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I've been trying to find the Distribution Group maintenance form in Dynamics AX 2012 but I could not find it anywhere in the AX client. I can open the form via AOT but not in the client.

Does someone know where to find the Distribution group maintenance form in the AX client?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think form `RetailConnDistributionGroup` can only be opened by right-clicking the distribution group Id field in another form and selecting 'View details'.

However there is a display menu item with the same name, which you can drag and drop to any menu so that the form can be opened from an area page.

Comment: hmmm, what form are you talking about when you say "right-clicking the distribution group Id field in another form and selecting 'View details"? I also think it works that way but I couldn't find that form.

Comment: Product information management > Common > Released products > Retail > Product label > Distribution group

Comment: That answered my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Cross Reference? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa626961.aspx

Comment: Well, it can answer all these sort of questions, and more, like where is a field changed etc.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought of cross-reference -> update since it usually takes a lot of time.

Comment: It is run as a batch job on AOS and you can schedule it so that it doesn't affect your work.